# Python console commands ignored

Tags: python, command-line

My computer seems to be completely ignoring everything I do with python. Every time I try to open a .py file, the console shows up for a split second, then closes immediately. This happens regardless of the content of the file. For example, it happens when I try to open [this file](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), which is supposed to install PIP.

Additionally, whenever I open the command prompt and type any command which starts with "python", for example

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

The console completely ignores this command and produces no output.

I have tried going into my environment variables and adding the path "C:\Users\cp253\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8".
[This is what is in that folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAPvX.png). Could it be possible that I used the wrong path and there are more python files somewhere on my computer?

Comment: How did you install python originally?

Comment: @jawsem Downloaded Python 3.8.1 through python.org

Comment: What happens when you just type `python`? You should get the interpreter starting up and a `>>>` prompt. If you don't, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

1. uninstall current python
2. install it again and add python to the path, python installer will ask you to ' add to the path' check that box and install it.
3. run the particular command from any other directory.